# How do I secure Swagger.yaml file?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am building out an OpenAPI support for my project but I need swagger.yaml file to be available only to authorized users.

Swagger UI and Swagger Editor both seem to expect the swagger.yaml file to be accessible publicly.

I've thought of various ways of getting around it. One could be using "signed" URLs, similar to how S3 does it -- this way only people with a link can access it.

What is a good practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. On the [Swagger-UI github page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) there is a description of the `authorizations` parameter that can be set in `index.html`:

> An authorization object to be passed to swagger-js. Setting it here will trigger inclusion of any authorization or custom signing logic when fetching the swagger description file. Note the object structure should be { key: AuthorizationObject }

What I've done was setup a Node.js server that protects Swagger-UI. If the token is not set in cookies, it directs the user through the OAuth 2.0 flow, sets the cookie, and only then directs to swagger-ui.

Swagger-ui in turn has `authorizations` parameter set as follows:

```
authorizations: {
      "_auth": new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization(
          "Authorization", "Bearer "+ Cookies.get("MyAccessToken"),
           "header")
    }
```

The header is then passed to the the server when downloading swagger.yaml file.